# Property doesn't exist or is used in a manner inconsistent with schema settings

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007, managed-property

I am getting this error on my page.

> Property doesn't exist or is used in a manner inconsistent with schema settings.Microsoft.Office.Server.Search

After googling, I found that I need to add managed properties to fix this issue. But I don't know exactly which managed property shouldIi need to add to fix this issue?

Any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### To view crawled properties and managed properties

1. Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is an administrator for the Search service application.
2. In Central Administration, in the Application Management section, click Manage service applications.
3. Click the Search service application.
4. On the Search Administration page, in the Quick Launch, under Queries and Results, click Search Schema.
5. On the Managed Properties page, you see an overview of all the managed properties, the settings on the managed properties and the crawled properties they are mapped to. To view crawled properties, click Crawled Properties. To view crawled property categories, click Categories.

### To add a managed property

1. Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is an administrator for the Search service application.
2. In Central Administration, in the Application Management section, click Manage service applications.
3. Click the Search service application.
4. On the Search Administration page, in the Quick Launch, under Queries and Results, click Search Schema.
5. On the Managed Properties page, click New Managed Property.
6. On the New Managed Property page, in the Property name box in the Name and description section, enter the name of the new managed property. You can also enter a description.
7. In the Type section, select one of the following options for the property:
   o   Text
   o   Integer
   o   Decimal
   o   Date and Time
   o   Yes/No
   o   Double precision float
   o   Binary
8. In the Main characteristics section, select one or several of the following:
   o   Searchable
   o   Advanced Searchable Settings (optional, if Searchable is selected)
   o   Queryable
   o   Retrievable
   o   Allow multiple values
   o   Refinable
   o   Sortable
   o   Alias
   o   Token Normalization
   o   Complete Matching

**Important:**

If you want to be able to use this managed property as a refiner, you must select both Refinable and Queryable.

9. In the Mappings to crawled properties section, click Add a mapping.
10. On the Crawled property selection page, select a crawled property to map to the managed property and then click OK. Repeat this step to map more crawled properties.
11. On the New Managed Property page, in the Mappings to crawled properties section, specify if you want to include:
    o   All content from all crawled properties mapped to this managed property
    o   Content from the first crawled property that contains a value and, optionally, in which order.
12. In the Company name extraction section, you can optionally select the check box to enable company name extraction.
13. In the Custom entity extraction section, you can optionally select the check box to enable custom entity extraction. See Create and deploy custom entity extractors in SharePoint Server 2013 for the procedures.
14. Click OK.

**Important:**

You have to perform a full crawl of the content source or sources that contain this new managed property to include it in the search index. If the new managed property is in a SharePoint library or list, you have to reindex that library or list.

### To edit a managed property

1. Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is an administrator for the Search service application.
2. In Central Administration, in the Application Management section, click Manage service applications.
3. Click the Search service application.
4. On the Search Administration page, in the Quick Launch, under Queries and Results, click Search Schema.
5. On the Managed Properties page, find the managed property that you want to edit, or enter its name in the Filter box.
6. Point to the managed property that you want to edit, click the arrow, and then click Edit/Map property.
7. On the Edit Managed Property page, edit the settings and then click OK.

**Important:**

Some changes on managed property settings require a full crawl to take effect. See the table Search schema changes that require content to be reindexed for an overview of which changes require you to reindex the content.

### To delete a managed property

1. Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is an administrator for the Search service application.
2. In Central Administration, in the Application Management section, click Manage service applications.
3. Click the Search service application.
4. On the Search Administration page, in the Quick Launch, under Queries and Results, click Search Schema.
5. On the Managed Properties page, find the managed property that you want to delete, or enter its name in the Filter box.
6. Point to the managed property that you want to delete, click the arrow, and then click Delete.
7. Click OK.

**Important:**

If you delete a managed property:
•   Users can no longer run queries using this property.
•   A query rule that uses this property no longer works.
•   A custom search application or web part that uses this property no longer works.
•   To delete this property from the search index, you'll have to perform a full crawl. If the deleted property was in a SharePoint library or list, you'll have to reindex that library or list.

### To map a crawled property to a managed property

1. Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is an administrator for the Search service application.
2. In Central Administration, in the Application Management section, click Manage service applications.
3. Click the Search service application.
4. On the Search Administration page, in the Quick Launch, under Queries and Results, click Search Schema.
5. On the Crawled Properties page, find the crawled property that you want to map to a managed property, or enter its name in the Filters box.
6. Point to the crawled property that you want to map, click the arrow, and then click Edit/Map property.
7. On the Edit Crawled Property page, in the Mappings to managed properties section, click Add a Mapping.
8. On the Managed property selection page, select one managed property to map to the crawled property and then click OK. Repeat this step to map more managed properties to this crawled property.
9. In the Include in full-text index section, check the box if you want to include the content of this crawled property in the full-text index.
10. On the Edit Crawled Property page, click OK.

**Note:**

You have to perform a full crawl of the content source that includes the crawled property that you’ve mapped to a managed property for the new mapping to take effect. If the new mapping is for a SharePoint library or list, you have to reindex that library or list.
To view or edit crawled property categories

1. Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is an administrator for the Search service application.
2. In Central Administration, in Application Management section, click Manage service applications.
3. Click the Search service application.
4. On the Search Administration page, in the Quick Launch, under Queries and Results, click Search Schema.
5. On the Categories page, find the crawled property category that you want to view or edit.

a.  To view which crawled properties belong to a category, and which managed properties they are mapped to, click the crawled property category in the Categories page.

b.  To edit a category, point to the crawled property category that you want to edit, click the arrow, and then click Edit category.

You can find more details [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219667(v=office.15).aspx).